# Getting Default Constraints Information

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to get the Default Constraints information for a given table. I wrote something like this:

```
SELECT  c.name ,
        col.name
FROM    Rem.sys.default_constraints c
        INNER JOIN Rem.sys.columns col ON col.default_object_id = c.object_id
        INNER JOIN Rem.sys.objects o ON o.object_id = c.parent_object_id
        INNER JOIN Rem.sys.schemas s ON s.schema_id = o.schema_id       
WHERE   s.name = 'dbo'
        AND o.name = 'Desk_Hist'
```

But it doesn't return me the default value. So I tried a different way and the query is:

```
SELECT *
                FROM    Rem.information_schema.columns columns
                WHERE   columns.table_catalog = 'Rem'
                        AND columns.table_schema = 'dbo'
                        AND columns.table_name = 'Desk_Hist'
                        AND COLUMN_DEFAULT IS NOT NULL
```

But it returns me nothing.

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Default value is in column 'definition', try to run query without where:

```
SELECT  c.name , 
        col.name, 
        c.definition
FROM    Rem.sys.default_constraints c 
        INNER JOIN Rem.sys.columns col ON col.default_object_id = c.object_id 
        INNER JOIN Rem.sys.objects o ON o.object_id = c.parent_object_id 
        INNER JOIN Rem.sys.schemas s ON s.schema_id = o.schema_id
```

Comment: van c.definition returns me Null

Answer (score 1):

Your first query should work but you are only including the constraint name, nothing else, from the constraint table (`c.name`).

Try including `c.definition` in your select list