# SQL default constraint not listed in sys.default_constraints

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table which has a default value in a column. That default value is visible in `column_default` column of `information_schema.columns` table, but that doesn't show up in `sys.default_constraints` view.

Can anybody say why it is so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the default is showing in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` as something like `create default X as Y` then it exists as part of a [bound default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-default-transact-sql), a deprecated means of applying default values.

It will not show up in [`sys.default_constraints`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-default-constraints-transact-sql) because it isn't part of the more "modern" constraint system.

Comment: If I am creating temporary table with some default value columns and I want to drop the columns later then how do I get the list of default constraint of temp table ?

Comment: @Shell - use `constraint DF_Something default ...` to *name* the constraint when you create the column and then you won't have to find the name later.

Answer (score 0):

The default constraint details are showing in the `sys.default_constraints`. But it doesn't contains which column it belongs to.

Need to join with `sys.columns`, `sys.objects`, `sys.schemas` you will get the actual details. I'm passing the table name in the `WHERE` clause to get the default constraints details from the both tables:

```
SELECT c.[name], col.[name], c.[definition]
FROM sys.default_constraints c
INNER JOIN sys.columns col ON col.default_object_id = c.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.objects o ON o.object_id = c.parent_object_id
INNER JOIN sys.schemas s ON s.schema_id = o.schema_id
WHERE o.[name] = 'TableName'
GO

SELECT column_name, column_default
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE Table_name = 'TableName'
    AND column_default IS NOT NULL
GO
```

`sys.default_constraints` related code used from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8041628/2451726)

Answer (score 0):

I came across this page when trying to find answers and wanted to share my solution for anyone else in the same boat:

My problem was that I was trying to match the `sys.tables.object_id` with `sys.default_constraints.object_id`, when I should have been trying to match with `sys.default_constraints.parent_object_id`. Make sure you have the right column in your query.